# Element not receiving style from one of its classes

Tags: html, css, styles

Alright i have a button element as follows:

```
<button class='secondary row_1 col_1 not-sticky'>Button</button>
```

styling for secondary etc work, but it does not pick up the styling from 'not-sticky'. This is my basic styling:

```
.not-sticky { color:#FFFFFF; }
.sticky-state { color:#000066; }
```

When a button is clicked this code is run:

```
if ($(this).hasClass('sticky-state'))
    $same = true;

    //change old sticky classes to not sticky
    $('.sticky-state').removeClass('sticky-state').addClass('not-sticky');

    if (!$same)
        $(this).removeClass('not-sticky').addClass('sticky-state');// chain our jQuery methods
```

Once this is run, the styling from sticky-state does work properly and the text color becomes #000066.

Also - through the use of chromes inspector i was able to verify that the classes are changing between not-sticky and sticky-state properly, just the styling from not-sticky is not showing at all

What could be making the not-sticky styling from not being applied at all?

Thanks

Here is the whole style sheet: http://staging.easyzag.com/style.css

Comment: Post your complete button click handler here.

Comment: it seems to work now fortunately, i am just having trouble getting hover colors to work right now - roger that got that fixed now too.. im on a roll this morning

Answer (score 1):

It works in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c7XHX/

Don't know if `$same` was declared or not, but you always need to declare your JavaScript values.

Comment: $same is declared above what i showed, and yeah i have gotten it working in a fiddle as well. i posted the rest of my stylesheet if that might help show anything?

Comment: Applying the rest of the stylesheet changes nothing. It still works, no?

Comment: i literally have no idea what changed.. but after you said that i reloaded the page and it seems to be working now.. i was trying different things for like an hour and nothing worked and now it does.. hmmm hah

Comment: Since you are using jQuery you could make troubleshooting a bit easier: consider using `.data()` for state on elements, not classes or new variables with vague names. `if($(this).data('sticky'))` checks if the button has a sticky state.